# Freezing column in visualforce page bageblock section

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, pageblocktable, column

I have requirement to freez/lock firsrt 2 or 3 colums in a table which is implemented using pageblock table supose i have a page which displays all customer recrod details using pageblock table now i want to freez first 2 colums in that pageblock table.

I could find many links for html table using (Jquery,CSS,html etc)
but i coun't find any clue for bageblock table.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that, when you say you want to "freeze" columns, you want to prevent their values from being edited? It would also help if you included your Visualforce page.

Comment: @DerekF I think freezing as in 'freezing headers'

Comment: @Avinash it should be freez while scrolling horizantal (similar to Excel)